# Am I Missing Something? Changing Dictionary Value

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I've been messing around with this code for much longer than necessary. I'm changing to change the value of a dictionary entry depending on a person's choice.

```
while points <= 10:
    print "You have " + str(points) + " points left.\n"
    stats = {
      "Strength": 0,
      "Dexterity": 0,
      "Constitution": 0,
      "Intelligence": 0,
      "Wisdom": 0,
      "Charisma": 0
     }

    for i in sorted(stats):
        print i + ": \t" + str(stats[i])

    statInc = raw_input("\nWhere do you want to put your points? ").capitalize()

    if statInc in stats:
        points -= 1
        stats[statInc] += 1
```

I started off with the **stats[statInc]** as a if/elif that specifies the strings by name. I can't get the values to change, but the point number will decrease accordingly. I know this because I originally had **points** set to **10**.

I've never had this problem before with my other codes that revolved around dictionaries and their values. But I've tried tackling this from every angle and I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is changing because you are setting `stats` to `{"Strength": 0,"Dexterity": 0,"Constitution": 0,"Intelligence": 0,"Wisdom": 0,"Charisma": 0}` within your `while` loop. Every time it loops around, it will recreate `stats`, making it appear like it never changed.

The way to fix this would be to put the `stats = {"Strength": 0,"Dexterity": 0,"Constitution": 0,"Intelligence": 0,"Wisdom": 0,"Charisma": 0}` line before you enter your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first time messing around with while loops alone. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-instantiating your dictionary every time the loop evaluates. Move your initial `stats` declaration out of your loop (before it) so those values aren't reset continuously.

Note that you'll also want to test for `while points > 0` instead of `points <= 10` since you're starting at 10 and decrementing rather than starting at 0 and incrementing. You could also just test your max points value against `sum(stats.values())` to be sure you're getting the current sum rather than using a counter variable, though in this case it doesn't really matter.